# returning string of chars in C

Tags: c, algorithm

i compiled my piece of code and it worked fine using printf  , but i want it to be returned without being printed ..

```
char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{

    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    while (i != 0)
    {
        i--;
    }
    return str;

}

int main ()
{
    char *string;
    string = "amrani";

    ft_strrev(string);
}
```

The main thing here is to reverse the input entred ..
how can i  exactly use **return** , to return the full char given to my **var string**  , any tips ?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse it in place or are you trying to return a new string whose contents is the reverse of the input string? You tagged this "algorithm". Have you worked out an algorithm for reversing a string yet or do you need help with one? If the former, tell us the algorithm and show us your attempt to code it. If the latter, explain what you're stuck on.

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast reply , i'm all good with the algo , i just tagged algo because that is what i did first  , it's all good at algo .
my prob now is at that  c Code , And yep i want to return a new string whose contents is the reverse of the input .

Comment: Detail: "i want it to be returned" --> Cannot do this in C.  A _string_ is an array/sequence of characters up to and including the _null character_.   Arrays cannot be returned.  A pointer to a string can be returned though.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to create a new array inside a function and return it.

Comment: @SaadAmrani If you're good with the algorithm, why didn't you tell us what it is or show us your attempt at coding it? If the `ft_strrev` you showed was an attempt at coding your algorithm, it's not apparent (at least to me) from looking at the code what algorithm it's expected to implement. I can't even tell if it was supposed to reverse in place or not.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to doing this: make a new string and return it or mutate the parameter in place. Here's a new string version per your clarification comment. Note that memory is allocated for the new string and the caller is expected to `free` the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *reversed = malloc(sizeof(*reversed) * (len + 1));
    reversed[len] = '\0';

    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        reversed[--len] = *str++;
    }

    return reversed;
}

int main()
{
    char *string = "amrani";
    char *reversed = ft_strrev(string);
    printf("%s\n", reversed);
    free(reversed);
}
```

Note that many functions of this kind will include the length of the string as a second parameter so the function needn't call `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution inverts the string in place.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
  int len = strlen(str);

  for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
  {
    char temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[len - i - 1];
    str[len - i - 1] = temp;
  }

  return str;
}

int main()
{
  char string[] = "amrani";
  ft_strrev(string);       // return value of ft_strrev not used here
  printf("%s", string);
}
```

Be aware of the difference betwween this:

```
char string[] = "amrani";  // string is an array of chars initialized with "amrani"
```

and this:

```
char *string = "amrani";   // string is a pointer to the string literal "amrani"
```

Modifying a string literal results in undefined behaviour, most likely some crash on modern platforms.

Comment: i'm not allowed to use for() or any other lib  that is what makes it hard .

Comment: @SaadAmrani You can write your own `strlen` easily, it's 3 lines of code. And you can use `while` instead of `for` easily, this adds another 2 lines of code. I leave this as an exercise for you. Hint: google "for vs while c". BTW not allowing to use `for` is really a stupid requirement.